Why do diffusions learns accumulated noise and not intermediate noise?
The core step is to learn scoring function: $L=\int E_{X_t}\|S_\theta(X_t,t)-\nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t)\|dt$, where $X_t$ is a forward-noise process and $p_{t}(x)$ is a density of X_t.
The trick to actually minimize it is to use simple equality $E_{X_t}\left[\langle S_\theta(X_t,t),\ \nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t)\rangle\right]=E_{X_s,X_t}\left[\langle S_\theta(X_t,t),\ \nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_s)\rangle\right],\quad 0\leq s<t\leq T$
This allows us to rewrite L in the form $L=\int E_{X_t}\|S_\theta(X_t,t)-\nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_s)\|dt$. which enables an easy-to-compute Monte Carlo approximation: $L\approx \sum\limits_{t=0}^T\|S_\theta(X_t,t)- \nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_{s})\|$. However, it's important to note that errors in approximating $\nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_{0})$ for large t can be quite significant.
My question is: why do we need to take s=0? My intuition suggests that it might be more logical to train the loss function in the form $L\approx \sum\limits_{t=0}^T\|S_\theta(X_t,t)- \nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_{t-1})\|$ as $\nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t|X_{t-1})$ is much easier to approximate. While this approach would slightly alter the original loss function, it probably should still effectively learn $\nabla\ln p_{t}(X_t)$. Perhaps the problem will be in the guidance-free approach?
